# What is the easiest and most simple way of creating webservice (SOAP) using Spring?

Tags: web-services, spring, soap, apache-axis, cxf

i am not familiar with the most optimal and easy way on how to develop webservices using Spring. We are going to use Tomcat as our application container, so i was wondering what the most easy way would be to develop webservices using Spring running on Tomcat? Should i use CXF/Axis or something else? We are planning to use the code-first approach.

Currently we already have some nice Spring beans as services and it would be great if we could expose them as SOAP endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

If you use code first, I would suggest Apache CXF with the [jax-ws front end](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws.html) or the [simple front end](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/simple.html)

The JAX-WS version is more powerful, but the Simple Frontend decouples your code from the framework (you don't need to annotate your services). Both are simple to create and work reliably.

Comment: Is there any working example on how to integrate CXF with Spring that you know?